Next.js - Mongoose - Vercel Deploying Problem
async function fetchImages() {
  try {
    const newURL = process.env.NEXTAUTH;
    clg(newURL)
    const res = await fetch(`${newURL}/api/images`, { next: { revalidate: 3600 } });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Image fetch failed with status ${res.status}`);
    }

    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching images:", error);
    // Handle errors gracefully on the frontend (e.g., display an error message)
  }
}

import { Image } from "@/lib/models";
import { connectToDb } from "@/lib/utils";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (request) => {
    try {
        connectToDb();

        const images = await Image.find();
        return NextResponse.json(images);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch Images");
    }
};


[21:18:40.423] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[21:18:40.547] Cloning github.com/tahirbera/try-for-vercel (Branch: master, Commit: ce69431)
[21:18:40.850] Cloning completed: 302.73ms
[21:18:43.346] Restored build cache
[21:18:43.437] Running "vercel build"
[21:18:43.903] Vercel CLI 34.3.0
[21:18:44.290] Installing dependencies...
[21:18:45.739] 
[21:18:45.740] added 20 packages in 1s
[21:18:45.740] 
[21:18:45.740] 4 packages are looking for funding
[21:18:45.740]   run `npm fund` for details
[21:18:45.750] Detected Next.js version: 14.2.5
[21:18:45.754] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+
[21:18:45.754] Running "npm run build"
[21:18:46.599] 
[21:18:46.599] > my-app@0.1.0 build
[21:18:46.599] > next build
[21:18:46.600] 
[21:18:47.299]   ▲ Next.js 14.2.5
[21:18:47.300]   - Environments: .env
[21:18:47.301] 
[21:18:47.375]    Creating an optimized production build ...
[21:18:55.174]  ✓ Compiled successfully
[21:18:55.175]    Linting and checking validity of types ...
[21:18:55.309]    Collecting page data ...
[21:18:56.559]    Generating static pages (0/6) ...
[21:18:56.615]    Generating static pages (1/6) 
[21:18:56.869]    Generating static pages (2/6) 
[21:18:56.961]    Generating static pages (4/6) 
[21:18:57.089] Error fetching images: Error: Image fetch failed with status 404
[21:18:57.090]     at o (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:6:29169)
[21:18:57.090]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[21:18:57.090]     at async a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:6:29317)
[21:18:57.090] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
[21:18:57.090]     at a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:6:29397)
[21:18:57.090]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
[21:18:57.090]   digest: '1693403049'
[21:18:57.090] }
[21:18:57.157] Error fetching images: Error: Image fetch failed with status 404
[21:18:57.157]     at o (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:6:29169)
[21:18:57.157]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[21:18:57.157]     at async a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:6:29317)
[21:18:57.157] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
[21:18:57.157]     at a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:6:29397)
[21:18:57.158]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
[21:18:57.158]   digest: '1693403049'
[21:18:57.158] }
[21:18:57.158] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
[21:18:57.158]     at a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:6:29397)
[21:18:57.158]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
[21:18:57.158]   digest: '1693403049'
[21:18:57.158] }
[21:18:57.158] 
[21:18:57.158] Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[21:18:57.158] 
[21:18:57.158] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
[21:18:57.159]     at a (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:6:29397)
[21:18:57.159]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[21:19:07.195] MongooseError: Operation `images.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
[21:19:07.196]     at Timeout.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
[21:19:07.196]     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
[21:19:07.196]     at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
[21:19:07.200] 
[21:19:07.200] Error occurred prerendering page "/api/images". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[21:19:07.200] 
[21:19:07.200] Error: Failed to fetch Images
[21:19:07.200]     at b (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/api/images/route.js:1:1025)
[21:19:07.200]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[21:19:07.200]     at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:36258
[21:19:07.200]     at async eR.execute (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:26874)
[21:19:07.200]     at async eR.handle (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:37512)
[21:19:07.200]     at async exportAppRoute (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/routes/app-route.js:77:26)
[21:19:07.200]     at async exportPageImpl (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:175:20)
[21:19:07.200]     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:154:20)
[21:19:07.200]     at async Object.exportPage (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:236:20)
[21:19:07.200]  ✓ Generating static pages (6/6)
[21:19:07.201] 
[21:19:07.201] > Export encountered errors on following paths:
[21:19:07.201]  /api/images/route: /api/images
[21:19:07.201]  /page: /
[21:19:07.231] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[21:19:07.509] 

I have one problen on deploying my project to vercel.
In .env my NEXTAUTH is same url on my vercel project. When i change localhost 3000 it is working without any problem on local server. Can any one help me please? I try everything but still this is not working. Anyone can help me please.
I have one problen on deploying my project to vercel.
In .env my NEXTAUTH is same url on my vercel project. When i change localhost 3000 it is working without any problem on local server. Can any one help me please? I try everything but still this is not working. Anyone can help me please.
I have one problen on deploying my project to vercel.
In .env my NEXTAUTH is same url on my vercel project. When i change localhost 3000 it is working without any problem on local server. Can any one help me please? I try everything but still this is not working. Anyone can help me please.
